# How to prevent device from turning off in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building an Android application by cordova. I need to keep the application running and stop device turn off by press the power off button. Does cordova support this feature? Or do I have to write one plugin by myself? I didn't find a plugin who can do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent powering off an android device by Power button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24364283/how-to-prevent-powering-off-an-android-device-by-power-button)

Comment: Maybe also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077905/override-power-button-just-like-home-button